# magento get savings total of your cart

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I have been googling like mad here.. I want a simple thing.  Get the difference of the total price of all the products at the normal price, from the total special/tried/adjusted price of all the products in a cart.

IE: if I had 2 items in the cart that have the normal price attribute like

```
1 @ $5
2 @ $10
--------------------------
total = $15 Savings = $0
```

but I then I make a special price on #2 so the cart would be

```
1 @ $5
2 @ $5
--------------------------
total = $10 Savings = $5
```

Now I know I can use

```
$this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal());
```

To get the grand total, but I'm not 100% that is not without the shipping.. but that would be with the special price applied.  I would need the total normal cost too then I can do the simple math from there.

What I'm wanting to do is put these to numbers in the header and the side bar.. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

on product view page

```
<?php 
   $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>  

   if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'bundle'){
      list($_minimalPrice, $_maximalPrice) = $_product->getPriceModel()->getPrices($_product);
      $this->_price = $_minimalPrice;
      $this->_specialPrice = $_minimalPrice;
      if (!is_null($_product->getData('special_price')) && ($_product->getData('special_price') < 100)){  
         $this->_regularPrice = ($this->_specialPrice / $_product->getData('special_price')) * 100;  
      } else {
         $this->_regularPrice = $this->_specialPrice;
      }
    } else {
       $this->_price = 0;
       $this->_regularPrice = $_product->getPrice();
       $this->_specialPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
    }
    if ( $this->_specialPrice != $this->_regularPrice )
    {
       if ($this->_regularPrice > 0)
       {
          $this->_discountAmount = round( ( 1 - $this->_specialPrice / $this->_regularPrice ) * 100 );
          $this->_saveAmount = $this->_regularPrice - $this->_specialPrice;
       }
     }

    if ($this->_regularPrice)
    {
        $this->_regularPrice = strip_tags( Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice( $this->_regularPrice, true ) );
    }
    if ($this->_specialPrice)
    {
        $this->_specialPrice = strip_tags( Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice( $this->_specialPrice, true ) );
    }
    if ($this->_saveAmount)
    {
        $this->_saveAmount   = strip_tags( Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice( $this->_saveAmount, true )   );
    }
    if ($this->_discountAmount)
    {
        $this->_discountAmount = $this->_discountAmount . '%';
    }
```

so, there is `_saveAmount` and `_discountAmount`, use in your template but I didn't test it, be careful on production site.

Comment: Hello, that does work to show the savings of the current product in both the % and $ but this is not what I was looking to figure out exactly.  I guess there must be a way to list out the product list in the cart and then iterate over it and do this math, but I figured there was a quicker/leaner path to it since it's up in the head.

Comment: also, your mention is right, you should iterate the product collection in cart section.

Comment: oh.. ok.. no I didn't and will do.. was really hoping for a much simpler light approch then to calc for each then store and then do math on it all.... :/ seems like it'll take a bit to process..